# Elasticsearch - Too many open files after updating file limit

Tags: file, indexing, elasticsearch, limit

I'm running into this error even after I've updated the file limit per node with my ES cluster. My set up is a 6-node cluster with around 630 million documents indexed.

This error happened near the end of my restarting of the cluster:

```
    [2013-11-11 00:00:21,087][WARN ][index.engine.robin       ] [rap-es-3] [zt_2012][11] failed to read latest segment infos on flush
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/elasticsearch/data/Odine/nodes/0/indices/zt_2012/11/index/segments_e (Too many open files)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory$FSIndexInput.<init>(FSDirectory.java:410)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NIOFSDirectory$NIOFSIndexInput.<init>(NIOFSDirectory.java:123)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NIOFSDirectory.openInput(NIOFSDirectory.java:80)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.RateLimitedFSDirectory.openInput(RateLimitedFSDirectory.java:99)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.store.Store$StoreDirectory.openInput(Store.java:436)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.read(SegmentInfos.java:318)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$1.doBody(SegmentInfos.java:380)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:812)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:663)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.read(SegmentInfos.java:376)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.robin.RobinEngine.flush(RobinEngine.java:947)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.flush(InternalIndexShard.java:502)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.translog.TranslogService$TranslogBasedFlush$1.run(TranslogService.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here's the output from my node API:

```
    {
      "ok" : true,
      "cluster_name" : "Odine",
      "nodes" : {
        "J_vVn1gKQMmcDYADbcPlfw" : {
          "name" : "rap-es-1",
          "transport_address" : "inet[/141.161.88.174:9300]",
          "hostname" : "rap-es-1.uis.georgetown.edu",
          "version" : "0.90.3",
          "http_address" : "inet[/141.161.88.174:9200]",
          "os" : {
            "refresh_interval" : 1000,
            "available_processors" : 4,
            "cpu" : {
              "vendor" : "Intel",
              "model" : "Xeon",
              "mhz" : 1995,
              "total_cores" : 4,
              "total_sockets" : 1,
              "cores_per_socket" : 4,
              "cache_size" : "18kb",
              "cache_size_in_bytes" : 18432
            },
            "mem" : {
              "total" : "7.6gb",
              "total_in_bytes" : 8255045632
            },
            "swap" : {
              "total" : "7.9gb",
              "total_in_bytes" : 8589926400
            }
          },
          "process" : {
            "refresh_interval" : 1000,
            "id" : 31729,
            "max_file_descriptors" : 65535
          }
        },
        "hT_Z-JneS6uCem0M-7nTEQ" : {
          "name" : "rap-es",
          "transport_address" : "inet[/141.161.88.169:9300]",
          "hostname" : "rap-es.uis.georgetown.edu",
          "version" : "0.90.3",
          "http_address" : "inet[/141.161.88.169:9200]",
          "attributes" : {
            "data" : "false"
          },
          "os" : {
            "refresh_interval" : 1000,
            "available_processors" : 2,
            "cpu" : {
              "vendor" : "Intel",
              "model" : "Xeon",
              "mhz" : 1995,
              "total_cores" : 2,
              "total_sockets" : 2,
              "cores_per_socket" : 1,
              "cache_size" : "18kb",
              "cache_size_in_bytes" : 18432
            },
            "mem" : {
              "total" : "7.6gb",
              "total_in_bytes" : 8255303680
            },
            "swap" : {
              "total" : "7.9gb",
              "total_in_bytes" : 8589926400
            }
          },
          "process" : {
            "refresh_interval" : 1000,
            "id" : 10282,
            "max_file_descriptors" : 500000
          }
        },
        "-76vB5ISTUq4M7ESizP7og" : {
          "name" : "rap-es-4",
          "transport_address" : "inet[/141.161.88.177:9301]",
          "hostname" : "rap-es-4.uis.georgetown.edu",
          "version" : "0.90.3",
          "http_address" : "inet[/141.161.88.177:9201]",
          "os" : {
            "refresh_interval" : 1000,
            "available_processors" : 4,
            "cpu" : {
              "vendor" : "Intel",
              "model" : "Xeon",
              "mhz" : 1995,
              "total_cores" : 4,
              "total_sockets" : 1,
              "cores_per_socket" : 4,
              "cache_size" : "18kb",
              "cache_size_in_bytes" : 18432
            },
            "mem" : {
              "total" : "7.6gb",
              "total_in_bytes" : 8255045632
            },
            "swap" : {
              "total" : "7.9gb",
              "total_in_bytes" : 8589926400
            }
          },
          "process" : {
            "refresh_interval" : 1000,
            "id" : 2462,
            "max_file_descriptors" : 65535
          }
        },
        "xssBGLKITpicDcxdeEjr4A" : {
          "name" : "rap-es-6",
          "transport_address" : "inet[/141.161.88.179:9300]",
          "hostname" : "rap-es-6.uis.georgetown.edu",
          "version" : "0.90.3",
          "http_address" : "inet[/141.161.88.179:9200]",
          "os" : {
            "refresh_interval" : 1000,
            "available_processors" : 4,
            "cpu" : {
              "vendor" : "Intel",
              "model" : "Xeon",
              "mhz" : 1995,
              "total_cores" : 4,
              "total_sockets" : 1,
              "cores_per_socket" : 4,
              "cache_size" : "18kb",
              "cache_size_in_bytes" : 18432
            },
            "mem" : {
              "total" : "7.6gb",
              "total_in_bytes" : 8255045632
            },
            "swap" : {
              "total" : "7.9gb",
              "total_in_bytes" : 8589926400
            }
          },
          "process" : {
            "refresh_interval" : 1000,
            "id" : 2608,
            "max_file_descriptors" : 65535
          }
        },
        "wg_I5wBfRxqs6kdH-S_kww" : {
          "name" : "rap-es-6",
          "transport_address" : "inet[/141.161.88.179:9301]",
          "hostname" : "rap-es-6.uis.georgetown.edu",
          "version" : "0.90.3",
          "http_address" : "inet[/141.161.88.179:9201]",
          "os" : {
            "refresh_interval" : 1000,
            "available_processors" : 4,
            "cpu" : {
              "vendor" : "Intel",
              "model" : "Xeon",
              "mhz" : 1995,
              "total_cores" : 4,
              "total_sockets" : 1,
              "cores_per_socket" : 4,
              "cache_size" : "18kb",
              "cache_size_in_bytes" : 18432
            },
            "mem" : {
              "total" : "7.6gb",
              "total_in_bytes" : 8255045632
            },
            "swap" : {
              "total" : "7.9gb",
              "total_in_bytes" : 8589926400
            }
          },
          "process" : {
            "refresh_interval" : 1000,
            "id" : 2570,
            "max_file_descriptors" : 65535
          }
        },
        "lG0sqr95Q02Lt-iTCcg6qg" : {
          "name" : "rap-es-5",
          "transport_address" : "inet[/141.161.88.178:9300]",
          "hostname" : "rap-es-5.uis.georgetown.edu",
          "version" : "0.90.3",
          "http_address" : "inet[/141.161.88.178:9200]",
          "os" : {
            "refresh_interval" : 1000,
            "available_processors" : 4,
            "cpu" : {
              "vendor" : "Intel",
              "model" : "Xeon",
              "mhz" : 1995,
              "total_cores" : 4,
              "total_sockets" : 1,
              "cores_per_socket" : 4,
              "cache_size" : "18kb",
              "cache_size_in_bytes" : 18432
            },
            "mem" : {
              "total" : "7.6gb",
              "total_in_bytes" : 8255045632
            },
            "swap" : {
              "total" : "7.9gb",
              "total_in_bytes" : 8589926400
            }
          },
          "process" : {
            "refresh_interval" : 1000,
            "id" : 22580,
            "max_file_descriptors" : 65535
          }
        },
        "biDQwwn4R9GTkesZUlNW1g" : {
          "name" : "rap-es-2",
          "transport_address" : "inet[/141.161.88.175:9300]",
          "hostname" : "rap-es-2.uis.georgetown.edu",
          "version" : "0.90.3",
          "http_address" : "inet[/141.161.88.175:9200]",
          "os" : {
            "refresh_interval" : 1000,
            "available_processors" : 4,
            "cpu" : {
              "vendor" : "Intel",
              "model" : "Xeon",
              "mhz" : 1995,
              "total_cores" : 4,
              "total_sockets" : 1,
              "cores_per_socket" : 4,
              "cache_size" : "18kb",
              "cache_size_in_bytes" : 18432
            },
            "mem" : {
              "total" : "7.6gb",
              "total_in_bytes" : 8255045632
            },
            "swap" : {
              "total" : "7.9gb",
              "total_in_bytes" : 8589926400
            }
          },
          "process" : {
            "refresh_interval" : 1000,
            "id" : 5190,
            "max_file_descriptors" : 65535
          }
        },
        "A7E7I7R5SIib6RJPA3RNug" : {
          "name" : "rap-es-4",
          "transport_address" : "inet[/141.161.88.177:9300]",
          "hostname" : "rap-es-4.uis.georgetown.edu",
          "version" : "0.90.3",
          "http_address" : "inet[/141.161.88.177:9200]",
          "os" : {
            "refresh_interval" : 1000,
            "available_processors" : 4,
            "cpu" : {
              "vendor" : "Intel",
              "model" : "Xeon",
              "mhz" : 1995,
              "total_cores" : 4,
              "total_sockets" : 1,
              "cores_per_socket" : 4,
              "cache_size" : "18kb",
              "cache_size_in_bytes" : 18432
            },
            "mem" : {
              "total" : "7.6gb",
              "total_in_bytes" : 8255045632
            },
            "swap" : {
              "total" : "7.9gb",
              "total_in_bytes" : 8589926400
            }
          },
          "process" : {
            "refresh_interval" : 1000,
            "id" : 2500,
            "max_file_descriptors" : 65535
          }
        },
        "oQG-yfURTTWZiFC6eOwjAg" : {
          "name" : "rap-es-3",
          "transport_address" : "inet[/141.161.88.176:9300]",
          "hostname" : "rap-es-3.uis.georgetown.edu",
          "version" : "0.90.3",
          "http_address" : "inet[/141.161.88.176:9200]",
          "os" : {
            "refresh_interval" : 1000,
            "available_processors" : 4,
            "cpu" : {
              "vendor" : "Intel",
              "model" : "Xeon",
              "mhz" : 1995,
              "total_cores" : 4,
              "total_sockets" : 1,
              "cores_per_socket" : 4,
              "cache_size" : "18kb",
              "cache_size_in_bytes" : 18432
            },
            "mem" : {
              "total" : "7.6gb",
              "total_in_bytes" : 8255045632
            },
            "swap" : {
              "total" : "7.9gb",
              "total_in_bytes" : 8589926400
            }
          },
          "process" : {
            "refresh_interval" : 1000,
            "id" : 1291,
            "max_file_descriptors" : 65535
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Any idea why I'm still getting the error after I've updated the file limit to 65535/node (500,000 on one for a test).

Comment: I would expect at most a couple of hundred open per shard, how many shards to you have on a node?

Comment: So... did this issue go away after the full restart was complete or is it still happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had too many shards per node. I reduced them from 12 to 6 and it solved the problem.